# Chinese characters in a URL - Google index percent encodes them

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC.Net project, I have a lot of url's with Chinese characters in the path, such as:

http://zh-cn.greatpatent.com/PatentDetails/冲洗控制器

But I've noticed that when google indexes these pages, the url's get percent encoded instead of maintaining the original Chinese chars, such as:

http://zh-cn.greatpatent.com/PatentDetails/%E6%B5%B4%E7%9B%86

Is there something I need to change on my app to instruct google not to do this? Perhaps change the page encoding type?

Comment: That is the right way to deal safely with URLs. Even though you *can* have weird characters in URLs, this is safe in all encodings, so it's the preferred way.

Comment: it's so ugly though... there's no better way? I've considered changing to pinyin just to avoid this.

Comment: You may consider my below answer moot. I compared your two example URLs, thinking they were related. They are in fact not and the second one *is* UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: but- I've opened fiddler and traced my first url above- and it is actually sent to the server using the utf8 url encoding... even though the browser continues to show the Chinese chars. 

BUT: here's the weird part - I can click on these links inside my web app and they keep format in the address bar. Google shows them the same way, with Chinese chars... but when I *click* the link from google, the address bar shows the encoded url version. the heck?